# Killing dwarven caravans

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In dwarf fortress (version DF2012), you get a dwarven trade caravan each fall. I know your own civilization will not go to war with you when it gets killed in any way. But are there any other consequences for getting them killed?

Due to some construction malfunctions, all the fully loaded wagons got de-constructed, so now I can take all the goods that they where carrying. Will this have any negative consequences? Apart from them just bringing less goods to trade next year, and getting fewer migrants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is one significant [drawback](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.31:Trading):

> If you order your military to kill merchants from your own civilization, your soldiers will simultaneously become members and enemies of your civilization, resulting in a civil war within your fortress. When this happens, all current members of the fortress (excluding incoming migrants) will turn on each other yet they will still be seen as normal working dwarves in the status screens. This will only last for those who were alive during the attack, they will always be hostile to everyone including incoming migrants (yet they still do their jobs/ follow military orders and work as dwarves although they will interrupt other's work. They will not be shown as enemies in the Units screen).

Outside of that, if you don't really need incoming immigrants then it is okay to take their goods.

Comment: Oh my gosh that sounds crazeballs, I need to do it as soon as I get home.

Comment: That sounds like a nice bug :).

Comment: Ah, is that what's called a Loyalty Cascade? Er, nevermind, hadn't read the next answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you order your military to kill them you will get a loyalty cascade, leading to everybody turning on everybody. Killing them via other means will not cause that. Deconstructing the trade depot will let you take their goods without killing. There will not be any consequences beyond less trade and migrants.

Comment: Digging away slopes that wagons stand on also causes you to be able to take the loot. Sadly enough. Thanks